# Cannot read property 'toDate' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm getting `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'toDate' of undefined` in this piece of code. What could it be, that is triggering this error? The code runs and it shows on screen what I want, but I still get this error.

```
const pr1200 = document.querySelector('#comentarios-pb-preco');

function renderPreco1200(doc){
   let li = document.createElement('li');
   let name = document.createElement('span');
   let dat = document.createElement('span');

  if (doc.data() == "X"){
     console.log("Do not get this Value");
  }
  else {
     li.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
  name.textContent = doc.data().Obs;
  dateNow = doc.data().timestamp;
  dat.textContent = dateNow.toDate(); //This line

   li.appendChild(name);
   li.appendChild(dat);

   pr1200.appendChild(li);
  }
}

db.collection('Preco1200').get().then(snapshot => {
   snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
       console.log(doc.data())
        renderPreco1200(doc);
    });
});
```

Comment: It means that in your code, `doc.data().timestamp` is returning `undefined`.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line or use `console.log()` to print out the value of `doc.data()` and see what the `timestamp` property is.

Comment: It's crazy, on one line on the inspection it says {seconds: 1583170475, nanoseconds: 839000000}
seconds: 1583170475
nanoseconds: 839000000 from the log, and on another, referencing the same line, it says undefined. As I said, it gets me what I want and displays it on screen, but also gives me that error.

Comment: @Phacer - You are running `renderPreco1200` for each snapshot. One of those snapshots has no timestamp, the others do.

Comment: I see, the snapshot that does not have a timestamp should be X, so my if (doc.data() == "X"){} is not working then? I may have this if statement in the wrong json level...

Comment: You can account for `undefined` timestamps by setting `textContent` to an empty string when `dateNow` is `undefined`. `dat.textContent = dateNow === undefined ? "" : dateNow.toDate();`

Comment: @Hurried-Helpful that works well, if you want to answer the question with this solution I will accept it =D. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can account for `undefined` timestamps by setting `textContent` to an empty string when dateNow is undefined.

```
dat.textContent = dateNow === undefined ? "" : dateNow.toDate();
```